# slider on angularjs data

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, slider

I need to add slider that is auto moving with a speed of 4 seconds , scrolling by one element.I used bower component, angular-slick from vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/ , it is working fine with static data, but I am fetching data from server in controller with $http. It is not working with dynamic data.

landing.html

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in barsubData">

    <span> {{cat.subCategoryId.name | uppercase}}  </span>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
    // get subcat bar function
    var getsubcatdetails = function () {

        services.webscreensucatService($scope, function (data) {

            $scope.barsubData = data.data.stock;
            console.log($scope.barsubData);
        });
    }
    getsubcatdetails();
```

service.js

// webscreen subcat service
    this.webscreensucatService = function ($scope, callback) {

```
    // var data = {};
    // data.email = $scope.login.username;
    // data.password = $scope.login.password;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: constants.BASEURL + '/api/BranchManager/lcdScreenDataSubCategory?accessToken=xxxxxxxxx',
        contentType: 'application/json',

    }).success(function (data) {
        if (data.statusCode == constants.SUCCESS) {
             //  console.log(data);
            callback(data);
        } else {
            $scope.loading = 0;
            factories.invalidDataPop(data.message);
        }
    }).error(function (error) {

        factories.invalidDataPop("Invalid accessToken");
    });
};
```

Kind of DATA I am getting from server

```
{
 "statusCode": 200,
 "message": "Success",
 "data": {
   "_id": "57a87e09cae4c29148233157",
   "stock": [
     {
       "startingPrice": 120,
       "currentPrice": 153,
       "lowPrice": 120,
       "highPrice": 153,
       "basePrice": 120,
       "currentStock": 99,
       "totalStock": 100,
       "_id": "57a87f49cae4c29148233165",
       "Date": "2016-08-08T12:47:05.975Z",
       "subCategoryId": {
          "_id": "57a87e81cae4c2914823315d",
          "name": "Sauvignon Blanc"
       },
       "categoryId": {
          "_id": "57a87e48cae4c29148233159",
          "imageURL": {
             "thumbnail": "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/barsupply/profileThumb_12JURVq.png",
             "original": "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/barsupply/profilePic_12JURVq.png"
          },
          "name": "Wine"
        }
  }]
```

Please help me working with slider. I am free to use any angularjs slider which is working.
Thank you for the help.